# Kendo Grid: Display collapsible data inside Grid cells

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-grid

I am trying to show collapsible data inside a cell of Kendo UI Grid. In my Kendo grid there is a column as **Prices** & per row, there may be multiple values for this price column. To display all prices inside the particular cell, I tried below template.

```
 template : "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo'>Price</button>"
            + "<div id='demo' class='collapse'>"
            + "<ul>"
            + "#if (competitorPrice!=null){#"
            + " #for (var i=0,len=competitorPrice.length; i<len; i++){#"
            + " <li><b>#:competitorPrice[i].competitorName #:</b> #: kendo.toString(competitorPrice[i].price, 'n2')  #</li>"
            + "# } #"
            + "#}#"
            + "</ul>"
            + "</div>"
```

I just want to collapse data inside grid cells. I am using bootstrap3 & angularjs.

Above code gives me following error message in the console.

```
angular.js:9778 Error: Invalid template:'<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#" role='row'><td  role='gridcell'>#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') #</td><td  role='gridcell'>#:data.salesCount==null?'':data.salesCount#</td><td  role='gridcell'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo'></button><div id='demo' class='collapse'><ul>#if (competitorPrice!=null){# #for (var i=0,len=competitorPrice.length; i<len; i++){# <li><b>#:competitorPrice[i].competitorName #:</b> #: kendo.toString(competitorPrice[i].price, 'n2')  #</li># } ##}#</ul></div></td><td  role='gridcell'>#:data.availability==null?'':data.availability#</td><td  role='gridcell'>#:data.searchCount==null?'':data.searchCount#</td></tr>' Generated code:'var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput='<tr data-uid="'+(data.uid)+'" role=\'row\'><td  role=\'gridcell\'>'+( kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') )+'</td><td  role=\'gridcell\'>'+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.salesCount==null?'':data.salesCount)+'</td><td  role=\'gridcell\'><button type=\'button\' class=\'btn btn-info\' data-toggle=\'collapse\' data-target=\'';demo'></button><div id='demo' class='collapse'><ul>;$kendoOutput+='if (competitorPrice!=null){'; ;$kendoOutput+='for (var i=0,len=competitorPrice.length; i<len; i++){'; <li><b>;$kendoOutput+=':competitorPrice[i].competitorName '+$kendoHtmlEncode(</b> )+': kendo.toString(competitorPrice[i].price, \'n2\')  ';</li>;$kendoOutput+=' } ';;$kendoOutput+='}';</ul></div></td><td  role='gridcell'>;$kendoOutput+=':data.availability==null?\'\':data.availability';</td><td  role='gridcell'>;$kendoOutput+=':data.searchCount==null?\'\':data.searchCount';</td></tr>;$kendoOutput+=;}return $kendoOutput;'
at Error (native)
at Object.compile (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:25:7802)
at Object.d [as template] (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js:2:3856)
at init._tmpl (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:50:16130)
at init._templates (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:50:17717)
at new init (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:48:16763)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:26:4091)
at Function.each (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js:2:2881)
at n.each (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js:2:846)
at n.e.fn.(anonymous function) [as kendoGrid] (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js:26:4068)
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you forgot escaping special character # in ***data-target='#demo'*** 
just add \ backslashes in front # characters.